# ceiling cracks-spider web cracks

Tags: ceiling, cracks

[image: spider web cracks]

Hi, there’s such spider web cracks in our second floor room. Who should I ask for to fix this problem? It looks serious.

Comment: have you ruled out water damage?

Comment: What is above the crack? Is it an attic? An upstairs neighbor?

Comment: above is the attic.

Comment: To me it looks like someone was in the ceiling and caused the crack. I have done this my self when looking for Knob and tube wiring that the owner covered with insulation, found a hot circuit behind me while clearing the area on the dead circuit to replace. My fast movement caused a similar issue but worse. I see no water leakage or wetting that’s why I suggest a person did it.

Comment: The ceiling needs to be removed anyway, so it wouldn't hurt to open it up to see what is causing the damage. It looks like a puncture from something stiff.

Answer (score 0):

Any reputable contractor or handyman will be able to make the repair. It may be worth having them investigate further as to why the cracks are occurring.

You'll want to mention to them when they appeared and if they have increased in size recently.

If they haven't just appeared and if you live in a seismic area the repair is a matter of securing the loose sections with screws aand covering the cracks with Spackle.

Comment: I’d personally be more interested to find the cause of the crack. Given that neither crack line is parallel (nor perpendicular) to the wall (assuming the wall is the dark area in the picture), it’s almost certainly not a crack at the drywall seams which could easily happen with a shoddy drywall job. It looks like something from above hit the drywall and cracked it.

Comment: I agree, or maybe a structural piece in the ceiling has come adrift. Careful if anyone goes up there...

Comment: Remove the loose pieces to inspect the framing. I suspect there is a T-joint, and one of the pieces has shifted and fell from the joint.